# Signing android APK with only password

Tags: android

I know the step of siging the application.
problem is i lost my builded key for siging and i only know the password that key built with it. 
is it possible to make another key with same password and use it for sign porgram  to update  old one ?
or should i rename my application and make new one ?

Comment: so i guess if i know all the detail from last keystore configuration(password , date ,...) and i lost my key file
i cannot make update on same app any more?

Comment: Your guess is correct. The file is the key, not the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way that you can update the app in playStore.You must be create an new app with a new package name and remove the old app, then republish new app